# How to count number of inserted records in table using counter and print the count of inserted record in each job run using python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

i want to count number of inserted records in table using counter or any method and print the count of inserted record in each job run using python script .Sample code is given below ..Please suggest few solution for same..

```
 with Postgresql.Database(connection_pool) as db:
   --count number of rows inserted in bazaarvoicereviews table and print the count for every job run
   db.insert('externaldb.bazaarvoicereviews',data=rdata)
--count number of rows inserted in bazaarvoicereviewsresponses table and print the count for every job run
   for rs in _ClientResponses:
       db.insert('externaldb.bazaarvoicereviewsresponses',data=rs)
--count number of rows inserted in bazaarvoicereviewscomments table and print the count for every job run
   for rc in _ClientComments:
      db.insert('externaldb.bazaarvoicereviewscomments',data=rc)
```

Comment: which postgressql package do you use?

Comment: pyscopg2 package we are using to load data

Comment: Also we have created  own module :Postgresql to load the data into table

Answer (score 2):

If you use `psycopg2`, you can get the rowcount from your cursor:

```
cursor.execute(statement)
rowcount = cursor.rowcount
conn.commit()
```

Full example:

```
import psycopg2

class CustomPostgres:
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn_string = "connection_string"
        self.conn = psycopg2.connect(self.conn_string)
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

    def insert_with_rowcount(self, statement):
        self.cursor.execute(statement, params)
        rowcount = self.cursor.rowcount
        self.conn.commit()
        return rowcount
```

Comment: i donot think it will work with my code ...                                                                            
    with Postgresql.Database(connection_pool) as db:
   --count number of rows inserted in bazaarvoicereviews table and print the count for every job run
   db.insert('externaldb.bazaarvoicereviews',data=rdata)
   for rs in _ClientResponses:
       db.insert('externaldb.bazaarvoicereviewsresponses',data=rs)
   for rc in _ClientComments:
      db.insert('externaldb.bazaarvoicereviewscomments',data=rc)

Comment: Of course it won't work without changing a bit the implementation of your Postgresql class

Comment: Please share your insert implementation so I can help you add it there..

Comment: def insert(self, table, data, returning=None):
 """Insert a record"""
 cols, vals = self._format_insert(data)
 sql = 'INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES(%s)' % (table, cols, vals)
 sql += self._returning(returning)
 cur = self.execute(sql, list(data.values()))
 return cur.fetchone() if returning else cur.rowcount

Comment: please share it as part of your question, it is difficult to understand it without a clear code snippet.

Comment: btw, your insert function is missing commit()

Comment: insert function is part Postgresql module ..commit is there in that module ..can we use  counter functionality to count  number records inserted  in the table ??